# Table net-Snmp : Error in packet. Reason: notWritable (That object does not support modification)

Tags: c, ubuntu-12.04, snmp, net-snmp, snmpd

I'm working with net-snmp C API , i create a MIB file ( containt a table of information ).

After that i used the mib2c that gives me two file "myproject.h" and "myproject.c"

I copy this two files in the directory : /net-snmp/agent/mibgroup

and i compile like this :
1)  ./configure --with-mib-modules=myproject
2)  make 
3) sudo make install

and from a terminal i run this command : snmpd -f -L -Dmyproject
and i get the message below : registered debug token myproject,1
                              Turning on AgentX master support 
                              NET-SNMP version 5.7.2

My question is :

that when i try to run snmptable for this table i get the messsage : NO ENTRIES 
and when i try to make snmpset to this table : i get this massage

Error in packet. Reason: notWritable (That object does not support modification)

*NOTE : in my file myproject.c i followed the example given by the net-Snmp :data_set.c
http://www.net-snmp.org/dev/agent/data__set_8c-example.html

but my table has not been initialisated

please i need help

thanks in advance

---

thanks K1eran for your reply .

the problem that i have it's not because of a badcommunity , here is my community configuration in the file of snmpd located in /usr/local/share/snmp:

## full access from the localhost

rocommunity public localhost 
rwcommunity private

really i don't know what is the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly related to community strings i.e. snmpset's -c flag . It would be better to see details of snmpset and snmptable commands however as described at : 
[net-snmp snmpset tutorial](http://net-snmp.sourceforge.net/tutorial/tutorial-5/commands/snmpset.html) ...

> Note that if you don't have write permission to the object ...
>
> % snmpset -v 2c -c badcommunity  test.net-snmp.org ucdDemoPublicString.0 s "hello"
>
> Error in packet.
>
> Reason: notWritable

`

Answer (score 0):

In snmpd.conf file the "#rocommunity public localhost " default settings will be commented(meaning localhost public not permitted read/write),
so
UnComment the "rocommunity public localhost" and change to "rwcommunity public localhost" then restart the snmpd service and check